# Logging POST and GET Requests with Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to log all activity on my Flask web app using the flask logger. I know how to get logs of application errors as is mentioned in this link

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/logging/#logging

The problem with this is that it only returns logs for the first time that i go to the local server to launch the app. No logs are returned after that. Logs are only updated if i change something in my code but not when i log in to the app or go to different tabs within the app. What is the procedure If I want to get the logs for activity within the app?

```
@app.route("/cis", methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def main():
    form = ReusableForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':       
        if form.validate():               
            try :                   
                app.logger.info("Reached /cis")                                 
        else:   
    return render_template('cis.html',form=)
```

For example if i want to show "Reached /cis" in the logs when i visit "/cis" in my app what should be done?

Comment: What is your Flask version? How do you run your app, is it a built-in debug server or a WSGI server?

Comment: Flask 1.0.2 and i am running through the command prompt with SET FLASK_APP = xyz.py and then flask run